# Newbie problem with adding include wp_footer

Tags: plugins, php, theme-development

It's a long, long time since I cobbled together my site and in that time I've forgotten what little I thought I might just know.

I have the FooGallery plugin on this page https://www.oxonscalextricclub.co.uk/gallery/

With an update it suddenly went single column on me and a Google revealed the lack of wp_footer in the page might be the issue.

In the Wordpress page editor I added `<?php> include wp_footer() </?>` and that's fixed the column issue but the text 'include wp_footer' is actually rendering on the page.

Can anyone tell me, in very simple terms, what schoolboy error I've made and how to fix it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `wp_footer()` should not be in the page itself. It needs you be in the template your theme is using for that page. Twenty Seventeen _definitely_ has it, but your child theme might not. Check page.php or singular.php in your child theme. If `wp_footer()` is there, then that's not your issue.

Comment: Well, losing the include, adding the semi-colon has fixed the issue but I don't seem to have a page.php or singular.php in my Child folder. Should I be worried??

Comment: No. That just means they’re in the parent theme. Meaning wp_footer is not the issue. I bet if you change the text to anything random it will still work.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php wp_footer(); ?>
```

remove include and add a semicolon at the end.

Comment: Ah. And I'd also treated the php as html with opening and closing tags. Great stuff. Many thanks.